# WooCommerce login not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want users to be able to login to WooCommerce if not. But the loginblock is not visible. When inspecting the site I find this:

```
form.woocommerce-form-login{display:none !important}.woocommerce-form-login-toggle{display:none !important}.woocommerce-EditAccountForm fieldset,.woocommerce-EditAccountForm label[for='account_email'],.woocommerce-EditAccountForm #account_email{display:none !important}
```

But I cannot find where the code is added? And thus I cannot edit it. Does someone have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your browser's inspector you should be able to find out where this css code comes from.

[image]